# closed track manifest for andoid apps

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, ads

Sounds like a bad question, but Google has confused and baffled me again. I am trying to add ads to my app that's already in the play store, but any time I add a new update, it is telling me that I need to add permission to the AndroidManifest.xml. I have even had some assistance from hired help to help me. And yet, google wont recognize it. The latest suggestion from their team is below
*

As per checking, it appears that the closed track manifest doesn't include the permission declaration for com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID.

With that being said, you'll have two options to fix this issue, first update your closed track and include the permission declaration on your closed manifest... *

Before you ask, the other option was to update the info in the web console, which has been done many times. The only thing I could do is turn it off. No thank you.

My question is, what is the closed track manifest? Where would it be in Android Studio? What am I doing wrong? I have it in the manifest as